# How can I decode JSON with array and more JSON inside?

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, codable

I recently began with swift. I need decode the json on below.

The JSON has inside two more JSON the first one (validation) does not matter. The second one (result) has a JSON array inside (serviceCenter). I need the information of each servicenter. I try to use servicecenter as decodeable class to get a servicenter object, but as the JSON does not have the proper format I can't do it.

```
[
  {
    "validation": {
      "bValid": true,
      "sDescription": "Access true."
    }
  },
  {
    "result": {
      "serviceCenter": [
        {
          "model": "Vanquish",
          "color": "Purple",
          "make": "Aston Martin",
          "sTag": "3666",
          "sVin": "6JDO2345",
          "sMiles": "3666",
          "bDamage": "1",
          "dDateTime": "04-17-2018 9:38 AM"
        },
        {
          "model": "F360",
          "color": "Red",
          "make": "Ferrari",
          "sTag": "0010",
          "sVin": "6JDO2347",
          "sMiles": "80000",
          "bDamage": "1",
          "dDateTime": "04-17-2018 9:25 AM"
        },
        {
          "model": "Vanquish",
          "color": "Purple",
          "make": "Aston Martin",
          "sTag": "0009",
          "sVin": "6JDO2345",
          "sMiles": "25000",
          "bDamage": "1",
          "dDateTime": "04-17-2018 9:23 AM"
        },
        {
          "model": "Vanquish",
          "color": "Purple",
          "make": "Aston Martin",
          "sTag": "0003",
          "sVin": "6JDO2345",
          "sMiles": "20000",
          "bDamage": "1",
          "dDateTime": "04-12-2018 10:37 AM"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I try so much but i cant do it.

This its my  code now, Could someone help me please

```
do {
    let parseoDatos = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [AnyObject]
    let h = type(of: parseoDatos )
    print("'\(parseoDatos)' of type '\(h)'")
    let contenido = parseoDatos[1]["result"]

    if let services = contenido!! as? Dictionary<String, Array<Any>> {               
        for (_,serviceArray) in services {
            for sc in serviceArray{
                let h = type(of: sc )
                print("'\(sc)' of type '\(h)'")                        
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    print("json processing failed")
}
```

the result of print sc is

```
{
    bDamage = 1;
    color = Purple;
    dDateTime = "04-17-2018 9:38 AM";
    make = "Aston Martin";
    model = Vanquish;
    sMiles = 3666;
    sTag = 3666;
    sVin = 6JDO2345;
}' of type '__NSDictionaryI'
```

Comment: I would like to suggest this: you can use the great `SwiftJSON`. SwiftyJSON makes it easy to deal with JSON data in Swift. https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: What is your decodeable class? Please show me your code.

Comment: As @Glenn said, SwiftyJSON is a great tool. Alternatively, you could have a look at Swift's [`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encoding_decoding_and_serialization) protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Codable`

**Initial** response  have array of **InitialElement** and `InitialElement` is is struct with `validation` , `result`  , result may be **nil**

don't forget to add your URL  at `url`

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

                     if  let initial =  try? JSONDecoder().decode([InitialElement].self, from: data){

                         // inital now have array of InitialElement and InitialElement is is struct with validation , result  , result may be nil


                        print(initial)
                        }
                    }.resume()
```

With this Model for Data:

```
import Foundation

struct InitialElement: Codable {
    let validation: Validation?
    let result: ResultData?
}

struct ResultData: Codable {
    let serviceCenter: [ServiceCenter]
}

struct ServiceCenter: Codable {
    let model, color, make, sTag: String
    let sVin, sMiles, bDamage, dDateTime: String
}

struct Validation: Codable {
    let bValid: Bool
    let sDescription: String
}


extension InitialElement {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(InitialElement.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
enum ParsingError: Error {
    case wrongFormat(String)
}

do {
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
    guard let array = jsonObject as? [Any] else {
        throw ParsingError.wrongFormat("wrong root object")
    }
    guard array.count == 2 else {
        throw ParsingError.wrongFormat("array count != 2")
    }
    guard let dict = array[1] as? [String: Any] else {
        throw ParsingError.wrongFormat("can't parse dict from array")
    }
    guard let serviceCenters = (dict["result"] as? [String: Any])?["serviceCenter"] else {
        throw ParsingError.wrongFormat("can't parse serviceCenters")
    }
    guard let serviceCentersArray = serviceCenters as? [[String : Any]] else {
        throw ParsingError.wrongFormat("serviceCenters is not an array")
    }

    print("\(type(of: serviceCentersArray))\n", serviceCentersArray)

} catch {
    print("json processing failed: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for yours answers, it's my first question here, and i feels great all the help. Finally i can resolve the problem. Maybe not the best way, but here its the code:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if error != nil{
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        do {

            let parseoDatos = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [AnyObject]
            let h = type(of: parseoDatos )
            print("'\(parseoDatos)' of type '\(h)'")
            let contenido = parseoDatos[1]["result"]


            if let services = contenido!! as? Dictionary<String, Array<Any>> {
                for (_,serviceArray) in services {
                    for sc in serviceArray{
                        let h = type(of: sc )
                        print("'\(sc)' of type '\(h)'")
                        let valid = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(sc) // true
                        print(valid)
                        do {
                            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: sc, options: .prettyPrinted)
                            let serviceDecoded = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
                            if let scJSON = serviceDecoded as? [String:String] {
                                print ("--------------------------")
                                print("'\(scJSON)' of type '\(type(of: scJSON))'")
                                print ("--------------------------")


                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
```

i think later y try to use Codable as suggested, but for now the code is working ok. Thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

```
//try this it is working

let arrayMain=try?JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:jsonData!,options:.mutableLeaves) as! Array<Any>


//print(arrayMain!)

if let firstDictionart=arrayMain![0] as? [String: Any] {
    if let insideFirstDict = firstDictionart["validation"] as? [String: Any]{
       print(insideFirstDict["bValid"]!)
         print( insideFirstDict["sDescription"]!)

    }

}
if let resultDictionary=arrayMain![1] as? [String: Any] {
    if let serviceDictionary = resultDictionary["result"] as? [String: Any] {
        for array in serviceDictionary["serviceCenter"] as! Array<Any>{
            if let infoDicti=array as? [String: Any]  {
                print( infoDicti["color"]!)
                print( infoDicti["make"]!)
                print(  infoDicti["color"]!)
                print( infoDicti["sTag"]!)
                print( infoDicti["sVin"]!)
                print( infoDicti["sMiles"]!)
                print( infoDicti["sVin"]!)
                print( infoDicti["model"]!)
                print( infoDicti["bDamage"]!)
                print( infoDicti["dDateTime"]!)         
            } 
        }
      }

    }
```